# can I get 255 packets from VCP (virtual COM Port)?

Tags: usb, stm32, descriptor

I know the default setting value for 'VIRTUAL_COM_PORT_DATA_SIZE 64' at usb_desc.h for STM32 Library.
however, I want to get the 255 bytes at one time due to the long packets of our project.
So I have changed the following modify code point, I couldn't get the right value with problem for 'USB defect problem'.

```
/****** usb_prop.c **********/
DEVICE_PROP Device_Property =  {
Virtual_Com_Port_init,
Virtual_Com_Port_Reset,
Virtual_Com_Port_Status_In,
Virtual_Com_Port_Status_Out,
Virtual_Com_Port_Data_Setup,
Virtual_Com_Port_NoData_Setup,
Virtual_Com_Port_Get_Interface_Setting,
Virtual_Com_Port_GetDeviceDescriptor,
Virtual_Com_Port_GetConfigDescriptor,
Virtual_Com_Port_GetStringDescriptor,
0,
0xFF /*MAX PACKET SIZE*/ // default : 0x40
};

/****** usb_desc.c **********/
/* USB Standard Device Descriptor */
const uint8_t Virtual_Com_Port_DeviceDescriptor[] =  {
0x12,   /* bLength */
USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,     /* bDescriptorType */
0x00,
0x02,   /* bcdUSB = 2.00 */
0x02,   /* bDeviceClass: CDC */
0x00,   /* bDeviceSubClass */
0x00,   /* bDeviceProtocol */
0xFF,   /* bMaxPacketSize0 */ // default : 0x40
0x83,
0x04,   /* idVendor = 0x0483 */
0x40,
0x57,   /* idProduct = 0x7540 */
0x00,
0x02,   /* bcdDevice = 2.00 */
1,              /* Index of string descriptor describing manufacturer */
2,              /* Index of string descriptor describing product */
3,              /* Index of string descriptor describing the device's serial number */
0x01    /* bNumConfigurations */  }; 

/****** usb_desc.h **********/
#define VIRTUAL_COM_PORT_DATA_SIZE              255 // 0xFF, default : 64
```

please tell me how to modify in order to send as 255 bytes from USB packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it this way. The size of the packet is USB endpoint related and for the FS USB it is always 64 bytes. My advice is: ***do not modify any descriptors*** unless you really know what are you doing (which is not the case here).

How to receive larger chunks of data:

1. create a buffer
2. when data arrives copy it (append) to that buffer
3. check if you have received all data needed
4. if not go to point (2) else goto point(5)
5. Do something with the data (your large packet)
6. Reset the buffer and goto point 2

Comment: That's ok! I have understand as reason about the abvoe issue. So I could get the under 64bytes.... (example 32bytes ok, 65bytes NG)

Comment: Is this the limitation of the CDC class (or some subclass)? Because although the max packet size is 64, a USB transfer can consist of multiple packets.